# C++ strTok implementation returning weird characters

Tags: character, strtok

I'm currently working on a string tokenizer in C++ and am getting a strange result.

```
    char *mystrtok(char *str, const char *delim)
    {
        char * LeftOver;
        bool lastToken;
        int i=0;    

        if(str != NULL)
        {
            LeftOver = str;
            lastToken = false;
        }else       
        {
            str = LeftOver;      
        }

        for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {            
            for(int j=0; delim[j] != '\0'; j++)
            {          
             //If I take out this line then it returns weird characters
                cout << "\tstr[" << i <<" ]" << "=" << str[i] << endl;
                if(LeftOver[i] == delim[j])
                {     
                    str[i] = '\0';
                    LeftOver = str + i+1;

                return str;
                }
            }
        }

        if(LeftOver[i] == '\0' && !lastToken)
        {
            lastToken = true;
            return str;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

What's really weird is that if I take out the cout then it returns weird characters
Any idea what could be causing this?

Here's a sample output

```
//passed
"ls -l -a | wc -c >>   myfile"
returned: ls
▒M.▒
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw several problems with this code, first

```
     str = LeftOver;
```

At this line, `LeftOver` has not been initialized at all. But you use it to initialize `str`. You want to make LeftOver `static`?

Second, your test for `LastToken`,

```
     if(LeftOver[i] == '\0' && !lastToken)
```

It will aways true for `!lastToken` since before this line it is always `false`, you want to make it static too?

Comment: Very true, however in the implementation one would pass the string that he would want to be delimited and then NULL to continue getting tokens from that string. For example: 
`char *next;
    next = mystrtok(string, delimiter);    
       
    int i = 0;
    
    while(next != NULL)
    {    
        next = mystrtok(NULL, delimiter);            
        i++;
    }     `
LeftOver should have a value if str==null. 
As for the !lastToken the code will loop through the code and find that there is no more delimiters and it's already returned the last token and then return NULL.